Is there a way to put multiple steps into a polars expression function?
I've been learning how to write expression functions in polars which are wonderful for creating self-documenting chained operations. But I'm struggling with more complex functions. Let's say I want to replace a value in column bar with the first value in column baz when baz is empty, over the group column foo.
To state more clearly:  I have a set of columns which form a a sorted group (in my example only foo). I have another column bar which may or may not have empty values. If the first value in bar for the group is empty ('' or NULL) take the corresponding value from a another column baz and apply to every bar in the group. If the first value in bar is not empty then do nothing to the group.
The below works correctly.
Initial DataFrame:
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame({'foo': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3],
                   'bar': ['a', 'a', 'a', None, None, None, 'c', 'c'],
                   'baz': ['x', None, 'q', 'z', 'r', None, 'y', 's']})

shape: (8, 3)
┌─────┬──────┬──────┐
│ foo ┆ bar  ┆ baz  │
│ --- ┆ ---  ┆ ---  │
│ i64 ┆ str  ┆ str  │
╞═════╪══════╪══════╡
│ 1   ┆ a    ┆ x    │
│ 1   ┆ a    ┆ null │
│ 1   ┆ a    ┆ q    │
│ 2   ┆ null ┆ z    │
│ 2   ┆ null ┆ r    │
│ 2   ┆ null ┆ null │
│ 3   ┆ c    ┆ y    │
│ 3   ┆ c    ┆ s    │
└─────┴──────┴──────┘

Transformation I want to perform:
df = (df.with_columns(pl.col('baz').first().over(['foo']).alias('temp'))
        .with_columns(pl.when((pl.col('bar') == '') | (pl.col('bar').is_null()))
                      .then(pl.col('temp'))
                      .otherwise(pl.col('bar')).alias('bar2'))
        .with_columns(pl.col('bar2').alias('bar'))
        .drop(['temp', 'bar2'])
      )

Expected Result:
┌─────┬──────┬──────┐
│ foo ┆ bar  ┆ baz  │
│ --- ┆ ---  ┆ ---  │
│ i64 ┆ str  ┆ str  │
╞═════╪══════╪══════╡
│ 1   ┆ a    ┆ x    │
│ 1   ┆ a    ┆ null │
│ 1   ┆ a    ┆ q    │
│ 2   ┆ z    ┆ z    │
│ 2   ┆ z    ┆ r    │
│ 2   ┆ z    ┆ null │
│ 3   ┆ c    ┆ y    │
│ 3   ┆ c    ┆ s    │
└─────┴──────┴──────┘

In my actual problem, this chain would be only a subset of a larger chain, so it would be great if I could write
def update_bar() -> pl.expr:
   return (#some voodoo)

and then:
df = (df.with_columns(update_bar())
        .drop(['temp', 'bar2'])
     )

or even
df = (df.with_columns(update_bar())
        .with_columns(pl.col('bar2').alias('bar'))
        .drop(['temp', 'bar2'])
     )

The first two operations at the top go  together so I'd really like to avoid writing two functions.
Any guidance on how to go about this?
Or maybe someone even has a more clever way to accomplish what I need all this code to do? Note that foo and bar having matching grouping is only true in this simplified example. In my real case foo is 3 columns and bar cannot be used as the group alone.

I think my answer may be incorrect.  using an example with the empty string case it produces different results: 'bar': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'x', '', None, 'c', 'c'] - Please check it if you can and accept the other answer if this is indeed the case.

It seems like the task could be achieved in a single expression?
df.with_columns(
   pl.when((pl.col("bar").first() == "") | pl.col("bar").first().is_null())
     .then(pl.col("baz").first())
     .otherwise(pl.col("bar"))
     .over("foo")
     .alias("new_bar")
)

shape: (8, 4)
┌─────┬──────┬──────┬─────────┐
│ foo ┆ bar  ┆ baz  ┆ new_bar │
│ --- ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---     │
│ i64 ┆ str  ┆ str  ┆ str     │
╞═════╪══════╪══════╪═════════╡
│ 1   ┆ a    ┆ x    ┆ a       │
│ 1   ┆ a    ┆ null ┆ a       │
│ 1   ┆ a    ┆ q    ┆ a       │
│ 2   ┆ null ┆ z    ┆ z       │
│ 2   ┆ null ┆ r    ┆ z       │
│ 2   ┆ null ┆ null ┆ z       │
│ 3   ┆ c    ┆ y    ┆ c       │
│ 3   ┆ c    ┆ s    ┆ c       │
└─────┴──────┴──────┴─────────┘

As an expression inside a function:
def update_bar() -> pl.Expr:
    bar_is_empty = pl.any_horizontal( # "easier" way to build | chains
        pl.col("bar").first() == "",
        pl.col("bar").first().is_null()
    )
   
    return (
        pl.when(bar_is_empty)
          .then(pl.col("baz").first())
          .otherwise(pl.col("bar"))
          .over("foo")
          .alias("bar")
    )

>>> df.with_columns(update_bar())
shape: (8, 3)
┌─────┬─────┬──────┐
│ foo ┆ bar ┆ baz  │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---  │
│ i64 ┆ str ┆ str  │
╞═════╪═════╪══════╡
│ 1   ┆ a   ┆ x    │
│ 1   ┆ a   ┆ null │
│ 1   ┆ a   ┆ q    │
│ 2   ┆ z   ┆ z    │
│ 2   ┆ z   ┆ r    │
│ 2   ┆ z   ┆ null │
│ 3   ┆ c   ┆ y    │
│ 3   ┆ c   ┆ s    │
└─────┴─────┴──────┘

There are also Frame/Expression pipe methods which may be relevant:

DataFrame.pipe()

LazyFrame.pipe()

Expr.pipe()



That's fantastic, and it works on my real more complex data too. I also like the any.horizontal trick - I can use that all over. I'm still trying to wrap my head around how doing a filter over a column inside a 'then' clause can work. I did something like that by accident before and I still don't know how it's possible. polars is amazing.

@MikeP It's similar to what you did with temp_col - Polars runs the .when() and .then() expressions in Parallel and "masks out" the false values - without needing to explicitly create a temp column.

@MikeP I think I may have misinterpreted what your code really does. e.g. using 'bar': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'x', '', None, 'c', 'c'] the results differ. (I thought you wanted the first baz when bar is null or empty) - So I think this answer is actually wrong - /user/Ramnath has shown a much simpler approach.

The results should differ with the bar input you suggest. It's the first row in the group that should determine what happens. In your example, the first row in the  '2' group is no longer null or blank, it's 'x', so a different result is expected. I neglected to specify what should happen if there are empty values in bar within a group where the first value was non-empty (your example).  In that case  I would prefer bar be left alone for the whole group. Your solution will instead take the value of baz from the first corresponding empty in bar.

Let me restate the requirement as clearly as I can. I have a set of columns which form a a sorted group (in my example only foo). I have another column bar which may or may not have empty values. If the first value in bar for the group is empty ('' or NULL) take the corresponding value from a another column baz and apply to every bar in the group. If the first value in bar is not empty then do nothing to the group. Hope that clears up any confusion. Thanks so much for the help!

Thanks for the updates @MikeP - it should now match the exact logic you've described.

An alternate approach to solve this would be to use pl.coalesce(). It also reads beautifully IMO:
Coalesce the first value of baz over foo with the value of bar
df.with_columns(
  new_bar = pl.coalesce(
      pl.col("bar"), 
      pl.col('baz').first().over("foo")
  )
)

UPDATE: Thanks to @jqurious for pointing out what the OP wanted.

It's a little more involved as they also want to keep the original non-null values from bar

If I replace the column name bar with new_bar, I get the same output as your solution.

I'm guessing that was how OPs code example was formatted - it already included the transformation. You would need to start with just the initial dataframe - in which case a single coalesce is not enough. I've edited the question to hopefully make that clearer.

By swapping the order in coalesce, I am able to match the output you get.

I think I overcomplicated the actual task. I thought the user wanted the first baz when bar is null or empty as opposed to just the first baz per group - my bad. I think using pl.col("bar").replace('', None) in your answer will also handle the empty string case?

No worries! Thanks for taking the time to engage on this. These discussions are so useful in understanding how to write idiomatic polars code!
